# JQuery Accordion size of panels and spacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been working on this Accordion for a few days now and just when I think I'm close to the end, something else, transpires.  First and foremost, I am new to CSS and JQuery so, I am not adept in quickly recognizing what may, or may not, be missing in the code.  I've gotten this far and am, essentially, trying to compile a complete "template" for the accordion and then adding the accurate content when configured correctly.  In a nut shell, I'm just copying and pasting the current content to make sure accordion is working correctly.  It is not.  I guess, I need to know how to make the panels bigger to allow for more content.  My ultimate goal is to place four images(logos) within each panel along with 4-6 text links aligned with that logo.  Panel 4 is about as close as I can get to what I am looking for, however, I cannot add the 4th image I am intending to.  I'm guessing this is a size thing but, I'm not exactly sure how to change it. Panel 3 will not allow me to add anything else at all.  It currently only has 1 image.  I add another  with image and nothing appears.  A few people here at SO have been gracious enough to help me get started with my code and, it seems, each person has made some changes to my code.  In other words, I tried copying and pasting the code from Panel 4 to Panel 3 and the accordion just becomes distorted.  I'm just trying to allow for 4 images and minimal text content in each panel aligned accordingly.  I know this is a lot but, I am trying to be as specific as I can. Thanks very much for your time and any assistance you may be able to provide.

FIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1008/

```
CSS:
#accordion {
width:100%;
margin:10px auto;
border:1px solid black;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion h2 {
clear: both;
cursor:pointer;
margin:0px 0px;
padding:7px 15px;
border:1px solid white;
background-color:#080808;
font:bold 22px Petua One;
color:#ffffff;
text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#accordion .content1 {
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:10px 15px;
color:black;
height:230px;
width:25%;
float:left;
}
#accordion h2.active {
background-color:#ff6600;
}
.content-wrapper {
display: inline-block;
}
.content-wrapper a {
display: block;
}

HTML:
<div id="accordion">
 <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   League Scores</h2>

<div class="content">
    <div class="content1"><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Pittsburgh Amateur<br> Hockey League</a><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt=" photo PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png"/></a>

        <br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Squirt</a>

        <br><a href="">Pee Wee</a><br><a href="">Bantam</a>

    </div>
    <div class="content1"><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">High Performance<br> Hockey League</a>

        <br><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png" width="90" height="90" border="0" alt=" photo HPHL_zps31e66fcd.png"/></a><br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Squirt</a>
       <br><a href="">Pee Wee</a><br><a href="">Bantam</a>
    </div>
</div>
 <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   League Standings</h2>

<div class="content">
    <div class="content1">Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League <a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Association%20Logos/PAHL210210_zps694744b9.png" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt="Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League - Pittsburgh, PA" title="Pittsburgh Amateur Hockey League - Pittsburgh, PA"/></a>

        <br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Squirt</a><br>Pee Wee


    </div>

   </div>
     <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   Tournament Scores</h2>

    <div class="content"><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg" height="100" width="100"  border="0"  alt="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA" title="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA"/></a>

        <br><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Minnesota Gone Wild"</a>



    </div>

     <h2><a href="" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/RTH%20Artwork/RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png" width="25" height="25" border="0" alt=" photo RTHNeoLogo10_zps4b3f5604.png"/></a>   Tournament Standings</h2>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="content-wrapper"><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/bff3d1c7-f51d-42b7-98e4-240bfe796619_zpse0bc7d8e.jpg" height="100" width="100" border="0" alt="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA" title="OneHockey - Laguna Hills, CA"/></a><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Minnesota Gone Wild<br>Texas Longhorn Shootout</a>

        </div>
        <div class="content-wrapper"><a href="http://s1314.photobucket.com/user/RTH13/media/Banner%20Ads/NSTESLogo_zps7c937049.png.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Banner%20Ads/NSTESLogo_zps7c937049.png" width="100 height="100" border="0" alt=" photo NSTESLogo_zps7c937049.png"/></a><a href="http://www.pahockey.com">Blizzard Challenge<br>Presidents Day Tournament</a>

        </div>
```

[Blizzard Challenge
Presidents Day Tournament](http://www.pahockey.com)

```
    </div>

JS:
$(function () {
$('#accordion .content').hide();
//$('#accordion h2:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
$('#accordion h2').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
        $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Just updated Panel 3 of your Fiddle  - http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/1009/ - with some copy of Panel 4. As you mentioned various people have already updated your code, and you're kind of new to CSS. Panel 4 contains the logos in a content-wrapper set to display: inline-block. I don't want to recommend any site but if you google for it there are some illustrated examples how the `display`  property effects the layout.

Comment: I'd also suggest pairing down your example to include just the minimum to illustrate the question/problem ...

Comment: it would help to organized your code, hide away all unnecessary content. so it will be easier for you and us to id a problem.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your input.  @matthias_h I kind of figured that Panel 3 might have been a case of "too many hands on board".  Is there anything I can do about the sizing of the panels themselves?  I have the accordion set at 790px on my site but, it seems I am only getting usage out of half of that in the panels.